# How does 'kubectl apply -f' update a deployment behind the scenes?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a deployment created with a YAML file, the image for the containers is `image:v1`.

Now I update the file to `image:v2`, and do `kubectl apply -f newDeploymentFile.yml`.  Does Kubernetes use rolling update behind the scenes to update my deployment or some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens exactly is controlled by the [`Deployment`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#updating-a-deployment) itself:

- [`.spec.stategy`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1.7/#deploymentstrategy-v1beta1-apps): `RollingUpdate` (default) or `Recreate`
- [`.spec.strategy.rollingUpdate`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1.7/#rollingupdatedeployment-v1beta1-apps): see the docs I've linked for the explanation of the `maxSurge` and `maxUnavailable`

(I assumed that by *deployment* you actually mean a `Deployment` type object and not speaking in general.)

Comment: Yeah this is what I was looking for, thanks! By `Deployment` I meant the kube deployment object.